# How to set required=false on a (int or boolean) @RequestParam without default value?

Tags: spring, rest, http-request-parameters

I need a rest get method that search books by multiple optional parameters. This is the method:

```
@GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<List<Book>>> findByAll(@RequestParam(value = "title") String title,
            @RequestParam(value = "author") String author, @RequestParam(value = "new", required = false) boolean new,
            @RequestParam(value = "category", required = false) int category) {
        Optional<List<Book>> bookList = booksService.findByAll(title, author, new, category);
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<List<Book>>>(bookList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

all of theese parameters should be optional.
For example, if all input are empty should return all the books from db.
required=false needs a defaultvalue but i cannot set a default value for new and category.

Comment: You cannot, those are primitives and always have a default value. Don't use primitives but the object wrapper if they are conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a primitive type optional, because that implies/requires nullability, and a primitive cannot be null - only an object reference can be null.

So, you can change the int to an Integer, and that can then be optional.

Comment: The same goes for boolean to be changed to Boolean

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible because it proceeds procedurally.

Instead, use @RequestBody and Deserializable object to get search value.